# Как сделать чтобы карточки были в середине и было расстояние между ими

Tags: html, css

Дело в том, что я нашел карточки товара в инете, ну мне их нужно повторить 5 раз и разместить в ряд, пробовал, изменял css - не помогает. Вот код с инета:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

#opis1 {
  color: #DCDCDC;
}

.price {
  color: #00FFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="frame">
    <div id="opis1">
      <div class="card">
        <!— Фотография -->
        <img src="../img/Фотка%20Ускорение.jpg" alt="Ускорение">
        <!— Название -->
        <h3><b><i>Ускорение Виндовс 10</i></b></h3>
        <!— Цена -->
        <p class="price"><b><i>50 P</i></b></p>
        <!— Описание -->
        <p><i>Расскажем как ускорить виндовс 10, буквально в 3 раза, за 5 минут!</i></p>
        <!— Корзина -->
        <br>
        <form action="mein.html" target="_blank">
          <button><b><i>Магазин</i></b></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Ну соответственно я начал изменять "класс" `section`. Менял по разному тег `position` и тд. Ну и пришел я как разместить карточки товара в ряд, только они слева, а хотелось бы чтобы между ними было растояние `30px` и были они в середине. Как это починить? Если у вас есть способ (т.к. у меня возможно коряво все работает), то пишите сюда.

Ну вот и мое решение:

```
section {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  top: 40%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Если вам нужен скрин, могу прислать. Буду благодарен если сделаете чтобы они были в середине.

Comment: Может для скриптеров это легкий вопрос, но я искал ответы 2 часа и ничего не нашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой способ использовать [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

```css
body {background-color: #ccc;}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

#opis1 {
  color: #DCDCDC;
  /* Нужный код */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #opis1 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

/* Нужный код */

.price {
  color: #00FFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="frame">
    <div id="opis1">
      <div class="card">
        <!— Фотография -->
        <img src="//i.imgur.com/VfLQata.png">
        <!— Название -->
        <h3><b><i>Ускорение Виндовс 10</i></b></h3>
        <!— Цена -->
        <p class="price"><b><i>50 P</i></b></p>
        <!— Описание -->
        <p><i>Расскажем как ускорить виндовс 10, буквально в 3 раза, за 5 минут!</i></p>
        <!— Корзина -->
        <br>
        <form action="mein.html" target="_blank">
          <button><b><i>Магазин</i></b></button>
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <div class="card">
        <!— Фотография -->
        <img src="//i.imgur.com/VfLQata.png">
        <!— Название -->
        <h3><b><i>Ускорение Виндовс 10</i></b></h3>
        <!— Цена -->
        <p class="price"><b><i>50 P</i></b></p>
        <!— Описание -->
        <p><i>Расскажем как ускорить виндовс 10, буквально в 3 раза, за 5 минут!</i></p>
        <!— Корзина -->
        <br>
        <form action="mein.html" target="_blank">
          <button><b><i>Магазин</i></b></button>
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <div class="card">
        <!— Фотография -->
        <img src="//i.imgur.com/VfLQata.png">
        <!— Название -->
        <h3><b><i>Ускорение Виндовс 10</i></b></h3>
        <!— Цена -->
        <p class="price"><b><i>50 P</i></b></p>
        <!— Описание -->
        <p><i>Расскажем как ускорить виндовс 10, буквально в 3 раза, за 5 минут!</i></p>
        <!— Корзина -->
        <br>
        <form action="mein.html" target="_blank">
          <button><b><i>Магазин</i></b></button>
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <div class="card">
        <!— Фотография -->
        <img src="//i.imgur.com/VfLQata.png">
        <!— Название -->
        <h3><b><i>Ускорение Виндовс 10</i></b></h3>
        <!— Цена -->
        <p class="price"><b><i>50 P</i></b></p>
        <!— Описание -->
        <p><i>Расскажем как ускорить виндовс 10, буквально в 3 раза, за 5 минут!</i></p>
        <!— Корзина -->
        <br>
        <form action="mein.html" target="_blank">
          <button><b><i>Магазин</i></b></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

Для избежания проблем с выравниванием придётся перейти на [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
body {background-color: #ccc;}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

#opis1 {
  color: #DCDCDC;
  /* Нужный код */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  margin-right: -20px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

#opis1 .card {
  display: block;
  width: calc((100% - 60px) / 3);
  max-width: 250px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #opis1 .card {
    width: calc((100% - 40px) / 2);
  }
}

/* Нужный код */

.price {
  color: #00FFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="frame">
    <div id="opis1">
      <div class="card">
        <!— Фотография -->
        <img src="//i.imgur.com/VfLQata.png">
        <!— Название -->
        <h3><b><i>Ускорение Виндовс 10</i></b></h3>
        <!— Цена -->
        <p class="price"><b><i>50 P</i></b></p>
        <!— Описание -->
        <p><i>Расскажем как ускорить виндовс 10, буквально в 3 раза, за 5 минут!</i></p>
        <!— Корзина -->
        <br>
        <form action="mein.html" target="_blank">
          <button><b><i>Магазин</i></b></button>
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <div class="card">
        <!— Фотография -->
        <img src="//i.imgur.com/VfLQata.png">
        <!— Название -->
        <h3><b><i>Ускорение Виндовс 10</i></b></h3>
        <!— Цена -->
        <p class="price"><b><i>50 P</i></b></p>
        <!— Описание -->
        <p><i>Расскажем как ускорить виндовс 10, буквально в 3 раза, за 5 минут!</i></p>
        <!— Корзина -->
        <br>
        <form action="mein.html" target="_blank">
          <button><b><i>Магазин</i></b></button>
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <div class="card">
        <!— Фотография -->
        <img src="//i.imgur.com/VfLQata.png">
        <!— Название -->
        <h3><b><i>Ускорение Виндовс 10</i></b></h3>
        <!— Цена -->
        <p class="price"><b><i>50 P</i></b></p>
        <!— Описание -->
        <p><i>Расскажем как ускорить виндовс 10, буквально в 3 раза, за 5 минут!</i></p>
        <!— Корзина -->
        <br>
        <form action="mein.html" target="_blank">
          <button><b><i>Магазин</i></b></button>
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <div class="card">
        <!— Фотография -->
        <img src="//i.imgur.com/VfLQata.png">
        <!— Название -->
        <h3><b><i>Ускорение Виндовс 10</i></b></h3>
        <!— Цена -->
        <p class="price"><b><i>50 P</i></b></p>
        <!— Описание -->
        <p><i>Расскажем как ускорить виндовс 10, буквально в 3 раза, за 5 минут!</i></p>
        <!— Корзина -->
        <br>
        <form action="mein.html" target="_blank">
          <button><b><i>Магазин</i></b></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: А можно сделать чтобы выранивание карточек было по середине? Не чтобы там были отступы и тд, хочется такой сайт чтобы если даже одна карточка осталась внизу, она была в середине а не как на строке

Comment: Добавьте к "нужному" коду `justify-content: center`

Comment: Не подскажете как сделать карточки поменьше? Куда надо добавить widht и height?

Comment: К самой карточке `.card`

Comment: спасибо, пробовал - не работает, кажется у меня 500 строк запутаны